# SQL Creating a function which checks variables to make a total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've made 2 views which calculates the profit per reservation.
One calculates the profit from bikes and the other one from accessories. 
Now when I tried SUMing them together, I get false reports. I found out why: something a reservation doesnt contain a bike or a accessory. This field gives a NULL return, which makes my SUM function unusable, because it lacks results.

I tried this:

```
    USE Biker
    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION fnMaxOmzet
        (
            @Fiets AS int,
            @Accessoire AS int

        )
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @MaxOmzet AS int

        IF @Fiets = NULL 
        SET @MaxOmzet = @Accessoire
        ELSE IF @Accessoire = NULL 
        SET @MaxOmzet = @Fiets
        ELSE 
        SET @MaxOmzet = @Fiets + @Accessoire

        RETURN @MaxOmzet


    END
```

But it isn't working because it gives multiple results..
Probably cause I am using '=' while it checking a list.
Does anyone know a way to make this function?

```
    SELECT * FROM dbo.vAccessoireOmzet
    SELECT * FROM dbo.vFietsOmzet
```

https://ibb.co/bTmJ26

Expected result: List of ID 1 - 100 and the total of AccesoireOmzet + FietsOmzet

Comment: "it gives multiple results" - what does this mean?

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.     This kind of error

Comment: Please edit your post with some DDL and Sample data. We are obviously missing some key details here, and without that, we can't help you further.

Comment: I've edited the original post

Comment: @MrEmper, where is your DDL? How does that SAmple data fit into your data? Which table does it belong to? YOu have 2 tables and one set of sample data. There should be two sets of DDL and 2 set's of sample data.

Comment: @MrEmper have a look [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/) on how to post a T-SQL question. Please follow the instructions **carefully** and edit you post. Then, comment and mention me when you're done.

Comment: I hope this is better @Larnu

Comment: No, I can't see any DDL or Sample data, or Expected results still. I haven't checked the image, but the link I supplied doesn't tell you to supply images. It shows you how to supply your DDL and Sample data using T-SQL. I've flagged this as to be closed for the moment, until we have some consumable data, and DDL. All the answers below have resulted in "wrong" answers, because we don't have everything we need. The problem, however, isn't the quality of the answers, but quality of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IS NULL` rather than `= NULL`.

But you could also use something like this:

```
USE Biker
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fnMaxOmzet
(
    @Fiets AS int,
    @Accessoire AS int
)
RETURNS int
AS

BEGIN

    RETURN ISNULL(@Fiets, 0) + ISNULL(@Accessoire, 0)

END
```

You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) for more information on the behaviour of `= NULL`.

Update:

I imagine what you might be looking for is something like:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(F.Huurovereenkomst_id, A.Huurovereenkomst_id) Huurovereenkomst_id
    , SUM(dbo.fnMaxOmzet(F.FietsOmzet, A.AccessoireOmzet)) MaxOmzet
FROM
    dbo.vFietsOmzet F
    FULL JOIN dbo.vAccessoireOmzet A ON F.Huurovereenkomst_id = A.Huurovereenkomst_id
GROUP BY ISNULL(F.Huurovereenkomst_id, A.Huurovereenkomst_id)
```

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 65
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: How are you executing this? Could you add your SQL to the question?

Comment: SELECT dbo.fnMaxOmzet((SELECT FietsOmzet FROM dbo.vFietsOmzet), (SELECT AccessoireOmzet FROM dbo.vAccessoireOmzet))

Comment: It will be the views that are returning more than one value - do you need to say `SELECT SUM(FietsOmzet)` rather than `SELECT FietsOmzet`, for example?

Comment: It needs to return all results, because these list are all connected to a Reservation_ID. I wanna have the total profit of each of them. Some have both values Fiets + Accessoire = Total, but those who haven't need to give  result also like Fiets + NULL = Total

Comment: I've updated with my answer with what I think you might be looking for in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use an inline Table Function. You'll find the performance is significantly faster.

NExt, you don't test for the value `NULL` by using the `=` operator, you use `IS NULL`.

This should cater for the logic you have above, however it is untested due to missing DDL and sample data:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnMaxOmzet (@Fiets int, @Accessoire int)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN @Fiets IS NULL THEN @Accessoire 
                WHEN @Accessoire IS NULL THEN @Fiets 
                ELSE @Fiets + @Accessoire
           END AS MaxOmzet
)
GO
```

OK, just seen your comment with this sql: `SELECT dbo.fnMaxOmzet((SELECT FietsOmzet FROM dbo.vFietsOmzet), (SELECT AccessoireOmzet FROM dbo.vAccessoireOmzet))`.

That syntax is just wrong, sorry. You need to use APPLY and a JOIN. This is **pure guess work** as we have no DDL and Sample data... however:

```
SELECT MO.MaxOmzet--, --**Your other columns go here**
FROM vFietsOmzet FO
     JOIN vAccessoireOmzet AO ON --**Your JOIN criteria goes here**
     CROSS APPLY dbo.fnMaxOmzet (FO.FietsOmzet, AO.AccessoireOmzet) MO;
```

Comment: Msg 513, Level 12, State 1, Line 34
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Because you're using a subquery. You use TVF's with `APPLY`. Without your original table, I can't give a true answer, however, something like: `SELECT YT.*, MO.MMaxOmzet FROM YourTable YT CROSS APPLY dbo.fnMaxOmzet  (YT.Fiets , YT.Accessoire ) MO;`

Comment: Yes it needs to contain the data I put in, see my comment to previous answer

Comment: The "data you put in"? Please edit your post with some DDL and Sample Data.

Comment: @MrEmper I've updated my post with how you need to use the Function. That Subquery isn't ever going to work, for a lot of reasons.

Comment: SELECT MO.MaxOmzet--, --**Your other columns go here**
  FROM vFietsOmzet FO
    JOIN vAccessoireOmzet AO 
    ON fo.Huurovereenkomst_id = ao.Huurovereenkomst_id --**Your JOIN criteria goes here**
    CROSS APPLY dbo.fnMaxOmzet (FO.FietsOmzet, AO.AccessoireOmzet) MO;

Comment: 2400
35226
141264
98667
38835
13020
61824
58342
42240
4340
55
17688
1679
31056
17391
28801
48370
95160
16080
3520
23670
5400
13475
26460
5480
72675
23250
18447
58100
9450
30008
10600
17775
34658
43050
13280
46260
22815
30020
21060
10395
44163
13640
18396
39800
39600
16422
39248
16515
60770
8910
32832
84735
10248
5353
32277
12495
29470
44198

Comment: This still doesn't work, because number 52 returns a value of 32832, while FietsOmzet number 52 is already like 167000

Comment: You've still not posted DDL and Sample Data. Also, it seems we need expected results.

Answer (score 0):

use coalesce thats position

```
USE Biker
GO

CREATE FUNCTION fnMaxOmzet
(
    @Fiets AS int,
    @Accessoire AS int
)
RETURNS int
AS

BEGIN

    RETURN  coalesce(@Fiets+@Accessoire,@Fiets,@Accessoire) from MyTableVar;

END
```